# visiblity:hidden of table-cell hides background-color of parent table-row

Tags: jquery, html, css, firefox

I have some forms that are structured using `display:table-row` and `display: table-cell`. On Firefox 52, I could hide a cell element using `visibility:hidden`, hiding the cell but keeping the structure defined by CSS (instead of using `display:none`).

On Firefox 64 though (and also chrome), when I hide the visibility of the cell, the parent table-row loses its background color on that position.

Here's a snippet showing the issue:

```css
#tableRow{
  display: table-row;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
.cell{
  display:table-cell;
}
#hide{
  visibility:hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="tableRow">
  <a href="#" class="cell">Visible</a>
  <a href"#" class="cell"id="hide">Not visible</a>
  <a href="#" class="cell">Visible</a>
</div>
```

I tried using `opacity: 0` but some elements are clickable or have different events and opacity on 0 won't help.

Any thoughts? Is this intended?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would consider box-shadow to simulate a background coloration and avoid this *bug* *

```css
.container {
  display: table;
}

#tableRow {
  display: table-row;
  box-shadow: -100vw 0 0 red inset;
}

.cell {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 10px;
}

#hide {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="tableRow">
    <a href="#" class="cell">Visible</a>
    <a href="#" class="cell" id="hide">Not visible</a>
    <a href="#" class="cell">Visible</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

*it's probably not a bug but I am not able to find any specification describing this behavior

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work best. Background color as transparent doesn't hide wrapped elements and using font-size 0 changes the table width. This however keeps things consistent.

Answer (score 1):

You can use trick with `color:transparent` and to prevent events(of `a`) use  `pointer-events: none;`

```css
#tableRow{
  display: table-row;
  background-color: red;
}
.cell{
  display:table-cell;
}
#hide{
  color:transparent;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="tableRow">
  <a href="#" class="cell">Visible</a>
  <a href"#" class="cell"id="hide">Not visible</a>
  <a href="#" class="cell">Visible</a>
</div>
```

With inputs:

```css
    #tableRow{
      display: table-row;
      background-color: red;
    }
    .cell{
      display:table-cell;
    }
    #hide{
      color:transparent;
      pointer-events: none;
      border:none;
      outline:0;
      padding: 2px;
    }
```

```html
<div id="tableRow">
      <a href="#" class="cell">Visible</a>
      <input href"#" class="cell" id="hide"/>
      <a href="#" class="cell">Visible</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Sounds good, but in my case there are inputs and other stuff that won't get hidden with color:transparent.

Answer (score 1):

```css
#tableRow{
  display: table;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
.cell{
  display:table-cell;
}
#hide{
  visibility:hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="tableRow">
  <a href="#" class="cell">Visible</a>
  <a href"#" class="cell"id="hide">Not visible</a>
  <a href="#" class="cell">Visible</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but this wouldn't work because the table-rows parent already has display:table

Answer (score 1):

Add `font-size: 0` option for hidden div.

```css
#tableRow{
  display: table-row;
  background-color: #e5e8ec;
}
.cell{
  display:table-cell;
}
#hide,
#hide>* {
  font-size: 0;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 0;
  background: transparent;
  width: 75px
}
```

```html
<div id="tableRow">
  <a href="#" class="cell">Visible</a>
  <a href"#" class="cell"id="hide">
    <input type="text"/>
    <button type="button">Click Me!</button>
    Not Visible</a>
  <a href="#" class="cell">Visible</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have inputs and other stuff inside each cell that won't get hidden with font-size:0. Maybe my the solution would be reestructuring the html? I'd be glad to know why this got broken all of a sudden though :/

Comment: This still doesn't fix the background color issue described in the question

Answer (score 1):

Follow the structure

```css
#tableRow ul {
    display: table-row;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
#tableRow ul li {
    display: table-cell;
}

#hide {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="tableRow">
    <ul>
  <li>
<a href="#" class="cell">Visible</a>
</li>
    
    <li>
<a href"#"="" class="cell" id="hide">Not visible</a>
</li>
    
    <li>
<a href="#" class="cell">Visible</a>
</li>
  
  </ul>
</div>
```